# How do I redirect using a relative URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect a Sign Out button from a dropdown on my page. When I click on the sign out as of right now it will go to localhost:3000/signout. I have tried:

```
export const SIGNOUT="redirect=www.google.com";
```

and it will simply replace the URL as localhost:3000/redirect=www.google.com.

I have tried :

```
<Route exact path={SIGNOUT}>
    <Redirect to={www.google.com}/>
</Route>
```

```
export const SIGNOUT="www.google.com";
```

This will redirect to google.com upon loading and won't even let me load my own webpage:

```
export const SIGNOUT= window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

**urlLists.js**

```
export const SIGNOUT= "www.google.com";
```

**App.js**

```
import {SIGNOUT} from "./utils/urlLists";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const {location} = this.props
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={SIGNOUT}>
                    <Redirect to={HOME}/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

I expect the results of this to redirect to Google upon clicking on the Sign Out dropdown option.

The actual result is either a redirection to:

```
localhost:3000/www.google.com
```

or the Google page is loaded and my localhost:3000 does not.

Comment: could you include the code for the sign out dropdown option please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to redirect *inside* your `Home` component. Take a look at this sample implementation.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <button
        name="sign-out"
        onClick={() => {
          // sign user out here
          window.location.assign("www.google.com");
        }}
      >
        Sign Out
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Home />, rootElement);
```

The `Redirect` component is nice for redirecting to an **internal route**. However, if you're kicking the user out of your app you should use something else like [`window.location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign).

Comment: Thanks this is roughly the solution I have used on mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import React from 'react'
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedComponent = () => {
 if (authFails)
    return <Redirect to='redirect=www.google.com'  />
}
return <div> My Protected Component </div>
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Excuse me. I'll do it that way next time.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever included in the "" is the thing added to the domain. For example export const SIGNOUT= window.location.replace("google"); will become localhost:3000/google.

If you want to use "www.google.com", try to import it as a thing of its own at the beginning of the page, like "import Google from "www.google.com", then use the {Google} element.